# Onmouse click display block - manipulation with clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery function is like so, and runs `onClick`:

```
function showDataBox(ID) {
    $j('#' + ID).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Each box has id, and `onClick` runs this function, so how can I set it up so that if I click on another box, then it will call `.hide()` on the one already opened?

Comment: Give all of the boxes you want to hide a class. Then hide all the boxes of that class and `fadeIn` the box with the desired ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an array with the IDs of all your boxes in it

```
var boxes = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

Loop through the IDs every time and fade them out.

```
$j('#' + boxes[i]).fadeOut('slow');
```

Then fadeIn the one you want

Comment: how can i here get automatic id's?

Comment: You will need to provide us with your complete code in order for us to give you an answer to that. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/  to input your html,css and javascript for that.

Comment: Can i provide url to this site?

Comment: Yeah you can provide a url of your site here. This will be better